# How to update value of input after change of dropdown which is populated by mysql?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have run into a problem and Im not sure where to start... 
So my problem is- I need to use a dropdown which is automatically populated by a query concatenating two fields to make a single full-name.
 Then based off the name of the person selected change the value of the text input to be the dob, then also update every change when a new name selected. I have tried using the onchange event for select but just cant work out the right combination.

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database') or die ('Cannot connect to db');

$result = $conn->query("SELECT id, dob, CONCAT(`space`,`firstname`,`lastname`) AS `whole_name` FROM `table`");
echo "<select name='id'>";

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              $data = $id
              unset($id, $name);
              $id = $row['id'];
              $name = $row['whole_name']; 
              echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';

}

echo "</select>";
?>


<input type="text" id="text" value="<?php echo "$data" ?>"/>
```

Things to note - due to the concatenate needing a separator 'space' has been added to a field. at this time the sql query works exactly as intended.

When loading the page in the current state the text field comes up with the correct value for the first name, but does not update when changing value of select.

Im new with PHP and mySQL - self learning as I go. Any help appreciated.

Comment: PHP is a server side language and all PHP execution will complete before the page is delivered to the browser. If you need to reach out to the database again, after the page has been delivered, you will need to use AJAX in JavaScript to hit a route which will return the needed data. Then use JavaScript to populate the form with that data.

Comment: Can you show us the code you use for change the value of the text input?? jquery i suppose you use

Comment: Sigma - as in the code above the small PHP script inside the value of  the input delivered the result.

Comment: Thank you dgeare I'll have to look into AJAX and learn to find what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ajax not needed here. You can just put the dob value as special attribute for each options, and then change the text input with javascript when the select value change.

Here the new select with dob in attribute :

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              $data = $id
              unset($id, $name);
              $id = $row['id'];
              $dob = $row['dob'];
              $name = $row['whole_name']; 
              echo '<option dob="'.$dob.'" value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';

}
```

and then update the input when the select change, here an example with jquery :

```
$("select[name=id]").change(function(event) {

    //get the dob attribute
    var dob = $('option:selected', this).attr('dob');

    // update the text input
    $("input#text").val(dob);
});
```